# Error en Wordpress,(instalation failed,could not create directory)

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

Con Ubuntu 18.04 en VirtualBox estoy trabajando con Wordpress. Quiero instalar un plugin, concretamente "Contact Form 7", pero me dice que no tengo el directorio creado cuando previamente descargué el plugin en la página de Wordpress, lo descomprimí y lo introduje en la carpeta "plugin" de la carpeta "wp-content". Le doy a instalar el plugin y me vuelve a decir que no tengo el directorio creado.
Pensé que sería algo de permisos, entonces fui con la consola y le di permisos a la carpeta wp-content, pero me sigue sin servir.

Adjunto captura de pantalla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué permisos has asignado a los directorios `wp-content` y `wp-content/plugins`?

Comment: Creo que estas dando los permisos de forma erronea, ya que ese error de normal es por falta de permisos. Prueba a hacer un chown -R www-data:www-data your-wordpress-directory

Answer (score 2):

Por probar aunque hayas indicado que lo hayas realizado, el usuario no tiene permisos para crear la carpeta o directorio. Desde un root o admin que tenga permisos puedes darle al user que no tiene permisos en dicha carpeta con:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.blabla
```

O puedes probar en la terminal también con:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 wp-content // Yo pondría 775
```

wp-content debería tener de ruta /var/www/html/project_folder/wp-content

O Puedes dar permisos via FTP dandole click derecho a la carpeta wp-content y ponerle el permiso 775.

En caso de tener todos los permisos prueba con todo el contenido con:

```
chown www-data:www-data /path/to/wp-content/ -R
```

Y revisa la configuración del fichero vsftp y claro, que tenga permisos también.

Ciertos plugins requieren que el directorio /wp-content/ sea escribible, pero en muchos caso te lo dejarán saber durante su instalación. En algunos casos, esto puede requerir asignar permisos 755. Lo mismo es cierto para /wp-content/cache/ y puede que /wp-content/uploads/ .

Los directorios adicionales bajo /wp-content/ deberían ser documentados por cualquier plugin /tema que los necesite. Los permisos variarán.

```
/   
|- index.php
|- wp-admin
|   `- wp-admin.css
|- wp-blog-header.php
|- wp-comments-post.php
|- wp-commentsrss2.php
|- wp-config.php
|- wp-content
|   |- cache
|   |- plugins
|   |- themes
|   `- uploads
|- wp-cron.php
|- wp-includes
`- xmlrpc.php
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.